# Pygame: Displaying number of moves, timer and a win / fail screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a kind of puzzle game and it's been suggested that I use Pygame. I have looked at some tutorials but I am unable to get certain things to show.

- Number of moves - I'm basically looking for something that will count how many times the numbers 1 - 6 are pressed.
- Timer - I'd like this to start when someone presses a key and stop after a condition has been fulfilled.
- Win / fail screen - I'm looking to have something pop up saying the user has won or failed depending on if certain criteria have been met.

Any help on getting these displayed would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly get familiar with pygame font module : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html
You will need a way to display string and numbers to the user. Simply make a font object, and render surfaces with the strings, to later blit them like any other bitmap you had.

Also i suggest to look into the time module: the pygame docs are really helpful : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html. Here you will use this module to create a small class Timer, with a Clock object to stop and reset, and update functions. In the update functions, you can add the delta(the difference between the last and recent call of tick()) to the overall time or simply depend on the functions given in the time module. You can call stop when a condition is satisfied.

Last, for the screen, you may want to divide your game/app into states, where the game state is only rendered and looped when a play flag == true. When the game is over, you can switch the state to win/lose state to display the information and probably a prompt if the player may want to play again.

Comment: The font module will be incredibly useful, thank you! As for the time, I was going about it all wrong before hand, your way seems much more effective. If I recall the name for what you were describing in the last paragraph is a boolean switch? (I may be making this up, a friend has mentioned it a number of times).

Comment: yes, a flag is a true false variable - boolean. Simply use while(playing) do something, if(exit or win or false) playing = false